# HP Ethernet Team occasionally "transitioning" from redundant to degraded. Is this normal?

Tags: windows, nic-teaming

Every so often a server mentions this in the System log:

```
The Ethernet Team has transitioned from Fully Redundant or Degraded Redundancy to Redundancy Lost due to a failed or degraded team member. Only one team member is currently active and is either OK or Degraded.
 
User Action 
View the Ethernet and Ethernet Team Member status in the HPE Network Configuration Utility (NCU) if you are using Windows Server 2008. For Windows Server 2012 users, view the status with Microsoft teaming Management UI.. View the System Event Log for additional information.
```

only to announce in the same log a few minutes later

```
The Ethernet Team has transitioned from Redundancy Lost or Degraded Redundancy to Fully Redundant, due to a failed or degraded team member recovering full functionality. The team and all team members are operating as configured.
```

There is no obvious reason for this, no cable disconnected, even temporarily, and no switch issues that I am aware of. Does anyone know if this is normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

That is absolutely not normal behavior, and it is an indication that you *do* have a problem. It will continue until you find and fix the problem, or the *other* link also fails (in which case you'll be dead in the water).

Check everything end to end including the NIC and switch port, but especially the cabling. This is where the problem is most likely to be found. Maybe a rat has chewed through it somewhere, or someone accidentally used low quality cable, or something else.